# Need all Customer Addresses (with unique IDs) from QuickBooks QBFC13

Tags: vba, quickbooks, qbfc

I have an application that connects to QuickBooks via QBFC13, downloads the customers (just name, ID and a few other details) and all the known addresses for those customers.  This all seems to work just fine, except there is no GUID or other unique identifier that I can see that uniquely identifies the address.  So, for example, the customer changes an address in QuickBooks, I need to know which one changed in the application.  Or, I send info to QuickBooks using an Address ID rather than an entire block of Addr1-5.  I thought the address name would be unique, but it isn't and can be blank.  It isn't practical or helpful to key off of the addr fields.
Does this GUID even exist?  Am I missing something really simple?  Is there a better way to do this?  The QB docs are atrocious!

The VBA used to grab the customers and their addresses follows (some code snipped for clarity).

```
    Dim respType As IResponseType
    Set respType = curResp.Type
    If (respType.getValue = rtCustomerQueryRs) Then
        Dim custList As ICustomerRetList
        Set custList = curResp.Detail

        Dim curCust As ICustomerRet
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim insSQL As String
        For i = 0 To custList.Count - 1
            insSQL = "INSERT INTO " & CustomerTableName _
                & "(CustomerID, QBEditSequence, Name, PhoneNumber, EMailAddress) " _
                & "VALUES " _
                & "("

            Set curCust = custList.GetAt(i)
            If (curCust.Sublevel.getValue = 0) Then
                insSQL = insSQL & "'" & curCust.ListID.getValue & "',"
                insSQL = insSQL & "'" & curCust.EditSequence.getValue & "',"
                insSQL = insSQL & "'" & Replace(curCust.Name.getValue, "'", "''") & "',"
                If (Not curCust.Phone Is Nothing) Then
                    insSQL = insSQL & "'" & curCust.Phone.getValue & "',"
                Else
                    insSQL = insSQL & "'',"
                End If
                If (Not curCust.Email Is Nothing) Then
                    insSQL = insSQL & "'" & curCust.Email.getValue & "');"
                Else
                    insSQL = insSQL & "'');"
                End If
                accessDB.Execute insSQL

                ' Add Bill to address
                If Not curCust.BillAddressBlock Is Nothing Then
                    If curCust.BillAddressBlock.Addr1 Is Nothing = False Then
                        rs.AddNew
                        rs!CustomerID = curCust.ListID.getValue
                        rs!AddressType = "B"
                        rs!Addr1 = curCust.BillAddressBlock.Addr1.getValue
                        If curCust.BillAddressBlock.Addr2 Is Nothing = False Then rs!Addr2 = curCust.BillAddressBlock.Addr2.getValue
                        If curCust.BillAddressBlock.Addr3 Is Nothing = False Then rs!Addr3 = curCust.BillAddressBlock.Addr3.getValue
                        If curCust.BillAddressBlock.Addr4 Is Nothing = False Then rs!Addr4 = curCust.BillAddressBlock.Addr4.getValue
                        If curCust.BillAddressBlock.Addr5 Is Nothing = False Then rs!Addr5 = curCust.BillAddressBlock.Addr5.getValue
                        rs.Update
                    End If
                End If

                ' Add Shipping Addresses
                Dim shpList As IShipToAddressList
                Set shpList = curCust.ShipToAddressList
                If Not shpList Is Nothing Then
                    Dim s As Integer
                    For s = 0 To shpList.Count - 1
                        Dim saddr As IShipToAddress
                        Set saddr = shpList.GetAt(s)

                        rs.AddNew
                        rs!CustomerID = curCust.ListID.getValue
                        rs!AddressType = "S"
                        rs!AddressName = saddr.Name.getValue
                        rs!IsDefault = saddr.DefaultShipTo.getValue
                        rs!Addr1 = saddr.Addr1.getValue
                        If saddr.Addr2 Is Nothing = False Then rs!Addr2 = saddr.Addr2.getValue
                        If saddr.Addr3 Is Nothing = False Then rs!Addr3 = saddr.Addr3.getValue
                        If saddr.Addr4 Is Nothing = False Then rs!Addr4 = saddr.Addr4.getValue
                        If saddr.Addr5 Is Nothing = False Then rs!Addr5 = saddr.Addr5.getValue
                        rs.Update

                    Next s
                End If

            End If

        Next i
    End If
End If
```

Comment: I'm not QuickBooks expert, but AFAICT from using their ODBC driver, there is no distinct address identifier (IIR the Address ID is something like "home address" or "work address"). In my experience, this is not uncommon. If you're mirroring the addresses, one solution is to hash it on your side, then table scan the QB entities and compare them to your stored hashes.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I was afraid of.  I was just hoping there was a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

used qb a few years back and reviewed some projects from that period.  mind you, this was extracted by the qb report writer inside the client that most assuredly delivers truncated record.

no predefined globally unique address idrntifier as a single field for a specific address.  the customer/vendor name is unique for thier respective bill-from/to, ship-from/to but a billing address can be the same as a shipping address and other companies can, and do,  use the same addresses. 
this is actually very common among several types of business.

so bill from 1 is a unique header/name for a vendor but  the address string itself can also appear in bill from 2, bill from 3 through 5 before moving to bill from street, street 2, city, state, zip, country and all these fields roll up to create a long address string simply named bill from.

sadly, all i have are xlsxm and csv.  no longer have access to qb  so i can't go in for a closer look that would actually provide  helpful information